# Snowflake node driver's 'isUp()' method returns wrong result for terminated connection

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, connection-pooling

I'm building a custom connection pool for the Snowflake node connector. I couldn't find any method in Snowflake docs to check if the connection is still valid or not. Looking through the 'snowflake-sdk' library I found a method named 'isUp()' which says it "returns true if the connection is active otherwise false".

But while testing this I found out that 'isUp()' returns true if the connection is kept ideal until it's terminated from the Snowflake side (i.e. not closed by my server). Due to this, my connection pool thinks it is still a valid connection and returns it to my query worker. And by querying using this connection I get "Unable to perform operation using terminated connection" error.

Is there any correct way/method for checking if the connection is still valid?

Comment: While we wait for an answer here, can you report the issue with specifics of your environment here? https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-nodejs/issues/new

Comment: I have reported the issue here https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-nodejs/issues/168